# Unable to get the unchecked checkbox values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a FieldItems dictionary in ASP.NET model and this dictionary has values as below.

Age - checkbox, Name - text, Company - text

In my view file I was creating controls based on key, value pair which are available in the dictionary.

```
<div class="row cloneMe">
    <table>
        @foreach (var item in Model.FieldItems)
        {
            <tr>
                @if (item.Value == "checkbox")
                {
                    <td>@item.Key</td>
                    <td> <input class="associationCheckbox" type="@item.Value" name="@item.Key" value="false" placeholder="@item.Key" /></td>
                }
                else if (item.Value == "number")
                {
                    <td>@item.Key</td>
                    <td> <input type="number" name="@item.Key" value="0" ng-required="true" placeholder ="@item.Key" /> </td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td>@item.Key</td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="@item.Key" value="" ng-required="true" placeholder ="@item.Key" /> </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>


    <span>
        <button type="button" id="associationAdd" class="btn btn-success" style="float:none;cursor:pointer" ng-click="RemoveWidget()">AddPerson</button>
    </span>
    <span>
        <button type="button" id="associationRemove" class="btn btn-danger" style="float:none;cursor:pointer" ng-click="AddWidget()">Remove</button>
    </span>
```

Adding to previousone, I can include/remove the chosen fields based on button click as using below code.

```
$("#associationAdd").on("click", function () {
    $(".cloneMe:last").clone(true).insertAfter(".cloneMe:last");
});

$("#associationRemove").on("click", function () {
    if ($(".cloneMe").length > 1) {
        $(".cloneMe:last").remove();
    }
});;
```

After Adding my controls on ASP.NET page, I was reading control values.

[image]

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        foreach (var key in formCollection.Keys)
        {
            var value = formCollection[key.ToString()];
        }

    }
```

On clicking submit button, I can read Name and age values. However, I can get only checked checkbox values.
If I have three checkboxes and all are unchecked then key of checkbox is not showing in formCollection of Acton Result.

I have tried the following way to set the checkbox state but no result.

```
 $("input:checkbox[class=associationCheckbox]").each(function () {

        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $(this).val('true');
        } else {
            $(this).val('false');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I was reading the checkbox value in ASP.NET Mvc and it should be true/false based on cheked state of checkbox. I have tried as below but no good progress. can someone sugget me what's wrong from my side.                $("input:checkbox[class=associationbox]").each(function () {

        $(this).on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                $(this).prop('value', true);
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).prop('value', false);
            }

        });

    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to the checked attribute of checkbox using jquery use:

```
$(this).prop('checked', true);
```

If you are using jquery version earlier than 1.6 the use

```
$(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

To check whether a checkbox is checked or not use:

```
$(function() {
    $('.associationbox').on('click', function() {
        if ($('.associationbox').prop('checked')) {
            alert('checked');
        }
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cpoLo9sL/)**

Comment: I was trying to set the value property based on checkbox status.I tried value = $('.associationCheckbox').is(":checked") ? "true" : "false"; but no result.

Comment: try `$(this).attr('value', true);` if you want to set the value property of checkbox and do you mean  you cant get whether the checkbox is checked or not

Comment: yes Shubham.You are correct and that is the reason I have above code.

Comment: To check if a checkbox is checked or not use `$('.associationCheckbox').prop('checked')` it return true if it is checked and false if not checked. Let me prepare a fiddle for you

Comment: Hi Subham, That is working but I have mutple checkboxes with the same class name.Here is the JSfiddle and I couldn't get the checked checkbox status.I am looping all the checkboxs and checking the status. https://jsfiddle.net/z13x2gtw/

Comment: @Balu Yeah because you are making two mistakes. One in your fiddle you did not include jquery and secondly you are trrying to search for checkbox with class 'associationCheckbox' but you have defiend class to be 'associationbox'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117664/discussion-between-balu-and-shubham-khatri).